# how do i calculate the line data (raycaster)

Tags: c

i'm trying to code simple raycaster in c using glfw library, stuck in the line drawing part (in  the void update's end). In my opinion, error appears because of the bad distance finding algorithm. Please help me, also comment other errors in the code if you can

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SCREENWIDTH 1920
#define SCREENHEIGHT 1080
#define MAPWIDTH 24
#define MAPHEIGHT 24

float boxPositionX = MAPWIDTH;
float boxPositionY = MAPHEIGHT;
float boxSize = 5.0f;

double posX = 22, posY = 12;  //x and y start position
double dirX = -1, dirY = 0; //initial direction vector
double planeX = 0, planeY = 0.66; //the 2d raycaster version of camera plane

double time = 0; //time of current frame
double oldTime = 0; //time of previous frame

int worldMap[MAPWIDTH][MAPHEIGHT]=
{
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,0,0,0,5,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};
void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS || action == GLFW_REPEAT) {
        switch (key) {
            case GLFW_KEY_A:

                break;

            case GLFW_KEY_D:

                break;

            case GLFW_KEY_W:

                break;
        }
    }
}

void draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(boxPositionX, boxPositionY);
    glVertex2f(boxPositionX + boxSize, boxPositionY);
    glVertex2f(boxPositionX + boxSize, boxPositionY + boxSize);
    glVertex2f(boxPositionX, boxPositionY + boxSize);
    glEnd();
}

void update() {
for(int x = 0; x < MAPWIDTH * MAPHEIGHT; x++){
      double cameraX = 2 * x / MAPWIDTH - 1;
      double rayDirX = dirX + planeX * cameraX;
      double rayDirY = dirY + planeY * cameraX;

      int mapX = posX;
      int mapY = posY;
      double sideDistX;
      double sideDistY;

       //length of ray from one x or y-side to next x or y-side
      double deltaDistX = (rayDirX == 0);
      double deltaDistY = (rayDirY == 0);
      if (deltaDistX == 0){deltaDistX=1e30;}
      if (deltaDistY == 0){deltaDistY=1e30;}

      double perpWallDist;

      //what direction to step in x or y-direction (either +1 or -1)
      int stepX;
      int stepY;

      int hit = 0; //was there a wall hit?
      int side; //was a NS or a EW wall hit?
if (rayDirX < 0)
      {
        stepX = -1;
        sideDistX = (posX - mapX) * deltaDistX;
      }
      else
      {
        stepX = 1;
        sideDistX = (mapX + 1.0 - posX) * deltaDistX;
      }
      if (rayDirY < 0)
      {
        stepY = -1;
        sideDistY = (posY - mapY) * deltaDistY;
      }
      else
      {
        stepY = 1;
        sideDistY = (mapY + 1.0 - posY) * deltaDistY;
      }

        while (hit == 0)
      {
        //jump to next map square, either in x-direction, or in y-direction
        if (sideDistX < sideDistY)
        {
          sideDistX += deltaDistX;
          mapX += stepX;
          side = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          sideDistY += deltaDistY;
          mapY += stepY;
          side = 1;
        }
        //Check if ray has hit a wall
        if (worldMap[mapX][mapY] > 0) hit = 1;

        if(side == 0) perpWallDist = (sideDistX - deltaDistX);
        }

        int lineHeight = SCREENHEIGHT / perpWallDist;
        int drawStart = -lineHeight / 2 + SCREENHEIGHT / 2;
        if(drawStart < 0)drawStart = 0;
        int drawEnd = lineHeight / 2 + SCREENHEIGHT / 2;
        if(drawEnd >= SCREENHEIGHT)drawEnd = SCREENHEIGHT - 1;
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(drawStart, drawEnd); // Start point
        glEnd();
        }
}

int main() {

if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT, "Box with Jumps Everywhere", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create GLFW window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

      while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        update();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        }

}
```

the code contains a map, window creation, camera, beams used to get data about the walls, distance finding algorithm. Everything except the last one seems to work normally

Comment: To draw a line, you need at least two calls to `glVertex2f`, each with coordinates for both the x and y axes. You seem to be calling it only once, and with two y coordinates.

Comment: I suggest you do things one step at a time. First, make sure you can draw lines. Then, try to draw lines for all x coordinates. Then, vary their heights. Finally, use raycasting to determine their height.

Comment: Don't mention it. Also, don't forget to update the question if you make any progress, as that may be useful to others. If you solve your problem, you can also post an answer. PS: Welcome to StackOverflow!